# Which is the dependent variable in the UCI Liver dataset?

Tags: classification, dataset

https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Liver+Disorders lists some papers which have used this dataset. I went to one, 
[Turney](http://www.jair.org/media/120/live-120-1428-jair.pd), and it says:

> The target concept was defined using the sixth column: Class 0 was defined as “drinks < 3” and class 1 was defined as “drinks ≥ 3”
>   Column seven was originally used to split the data into training and testing sets.

In support of this, the file [`bupa.names`](http://mlr.cs.umass.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/liver-disorders/bupa.names) says

> 7. selector  field used to split data into two sets.

This doesn't sound like a dependent variable.

But I went to another, [Jiang and Zhou](http://cs.nju.edu.cn/zhouzh/zhouzh.files/publication/isnn04a.pdf) and it says there are 6 attributes (hence, presumably, the seventh is the one they use as the dependent variable).

I also found [this](http://www.researchgate.net/profile/Peter_Rosen6/publication/239666316_The_Impact_of_Data_Perturbation_Techniques_on_Data_Mining/links/5409d44a0cf2d8daaabf98c9.pdf) which claims that the seventh variable is:

> a dependent variable with two levels, indicating presence or absence of a liver disorder

Are a lot of people doing classification on a completely random variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some time later, I can now answer my own question. I contacted the person who is named as donating the original data, Richard Forsyth. He confirmed that the final variable is *not* a dependent variable, but is intended as a train/test split. We wrote a short letter to *Pattern Recognition Letters* to point this problem out. A few more details here: http://jmmcd.net/2016/04/30/disorder.html

In summary, A LOT of people are doing classification on a variable that they think indicates liver disorder, but is actually just a train/test indicator. When I say A LOT, I mean hundreds, including in top ML venues. Also some people are drawing conclusions about liver disorder diagnosis and treatment.